# Font size change in svg included in pdflatex beamer document

Tags: graphics, svg, python

I include an [svg I created with matplotlib](https://github.com/Boltzmann/latextest/blob/master/test.svg) [(see here how - at the bottom)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968024/how-to-remove-axis-in-pyplot-bar) using pyplot.savefig("test.svg") in my latex document.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\includesvg[pdf,width=\textwidth]{test}
}
\frame{
{\Large\includesvg[eps,width=.5\textwidth]{test}}
}
\end{document}
```

Whatever I try, I cannot change the size of the fonts in the svg. 
Is it possible that way? What do I do wrong?
I would rather like to use python etc. because using a gui like inkscape is for graphs not the method of choice.

Comment: I tried to answer your question. Did you solve the issue in another way?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the manual of the svg package, you need a special kind of svg file which has a text component. Inkscape can produce this kind of file, but probably not matplotlib. The svg manual says:

> The work by Johan B. C. Engelen has further enhanced the ability of
>   Inkscape to split an svg into a text component that can be imported
>   into L A TEX, and an image component that can be imported as a pdf . 1
>   Consequently it is now possible to include an svg into a LaTeX
>   document where the text within the svg has been rendered natively by
>   LaTeX.